# Java.Lang.RuntimeException Unable to start Activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Im trying to add a Splash screen to my android app in Xamarin.Forms, but im getting a weird Exception that im trying to solve without succes. heres a screen of the Exception. I dont know why i need to use "Theme.AppCombat" ?? weird for me i cant solve this problem on my own.

[image]

my resources/values/style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
 [Activity(Label = "Ummah",
        Icon = "@drawable/Icon",
        MainLauncher = false,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(Xamarin.Forms.AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Never);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

and my SplashActivity.cs

```
 [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash",
              MainLauncher = true, 
              NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        }
   }
```

Comment: Have your tried defining your Theme.Splash as `<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat">`?

Comment: public class SplashActivity : Activity fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely this is because your activity extends from the `AppCompatActivity` thats why it is asking you to use a theme to match. try changing

`public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity`

to

`public class SplashActivity : Activity`

or use an AppCompat theme

Comment: Thanks! that fixed my Problem .